# Javascript Json Not Working

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, get

I've tried it, but I haven't found a solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
 url: 'https://api.firsatbufirsat.com/deal/browse.html?apiKey=FZTGT8NK3RTC5M2O&publisherId=609&cityId=42',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){  
  if(data){document.write(data.deals[0].title)}
 }

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: what is it supposed to do? and what does it actually do?

Comment: also I recommend putting a breakpoint on the success function. and maybe making an error function

Comment: It's not JSONP. That might be an issue.

Comment: I tried JSON but didn't work.

Comment: You will have to look at the request and response in the browser console.  Do you get a response?  Is it encoded correctly?

Comment: That api is not serving jsonp and isn't CORS enabled. Use a proxy. They probably don't want you exposing your api key in client

Comment: @James yes, I get response.

Comment: getting response and being able to access response are 2 different things. You are not getting jsonp formatted response

Comment: @James I have permission for the API.